# Story ID: Old scifi mag story about lost robot civilization

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, robots

I'm looking for the author/storyname/issue of a yarn from Galaxy or a similar 60s or 50s science fiction magazine. The plot was that in the desert on earth someone found an odd looking rock or round object. This was the brain of a long gone robot, which was all that was left of a lost robot civilization.The person in the story made a machine that displayed the robots memories, and a story of the robot civilization was told, before the robots brain finally burnt out completely.

Comment: Do you remember anything about the story of the robot civilization?